# enable macro paradise to expand macro annotations

Tags: scala, scala-macro-paradise

I wanted to check some examples with annotations in `macro paradise` and I am getting the error, as is specified in: [this example](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/annotations.html)

I have related the projects, the other scala macros (not with annotations) are working very well. I have included the library `paradise_2.11.6-2.1.0-M5` (in both projects also :( ). I think, I do not get what means with `*to enable*`. !? bthw, I am using Scala IDE in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By enable, I meant adding it as a compiler plugin, as e.g. in https://github.com/scalamacros/sbt-example-paradise/blob/17f4a0d421ad7002334c7081d3ec79cc9edb4f24/project/Build.scala#L14

Comment: Unfortunately in 2017 this broken again

Comment: add `addCompilerPlugin("org.scalamacros" % "paradise" % "2.1.1" cross CrossVersion.full)` to build.sbt